# Send request from PHP script to the Node.js script

Tags: php, node.js

Is there a way to send any kind of request from the PHP script to the Node.js script?

For example I have this directory:

```
scripts
|_sender.php
|_receiver.js
```

I want to send some data from php script and read it with node.js script to execute some action.

How is this done properly?

Comment: You can send a request with PHP (cURL or Guzzle) or you can setup a message queue or you could poll the DB. Lots of options but what is your use case? Why this node layer?

Comment: @nerdlyist Because our app is written in CakePHP and our Google API is written in Node.js.

Comment: So your node portion is a restful api? Then I would go for making a request to that with Guzzle. What is that receiver.js doing?

Comment: This is just example of their positions. I would usually run node.js script from php like this: `<?php exec('node receiver.js')`

Comment: Okay but what is receiver.js doing. Is it making the request to the node api?

Comment: It is a script such as this one in the example: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I use is to pass your PHP data to node using HTTP post or get, here is my code to send data from PHP to the node.

```
// Node Side
var express = require('express');
express = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
express.use(bodyParser.json());

express.post('/get_php_data', function (req, res) {
    // php array will be here in this variable
    var data = req.body.data;
    
    
    res.send(' Done ');
});

// PHP Side
httpPost('NODE_URL:2200/get_php_data', array('data' => 'some data'));

function httpPost($url,$params)
{
    $postData = http_build_query($params);
    $ch = curl_init();  
 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends where js will read it incoming data

If it is a server, start it with `node receiver.js` then send from your php to http://local host/.... Whatever your server is listening on

Or you can dump your php output into a file and read it by the receiver after

You should provide more informations to get a better answer